# Where is 'Class Actions' in the 'Object Identity' panel in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, nsobject

I thought I was fairly experienced at iPhone development, but I'm tripping up on the Stanford iPhone course on the [very first video](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225).

(38 mins in)

The teacher, drags an NSObject into the MainWindow.xib. And when he inspects the Object in the Identity Inspector (Cmd-4), there are Class Actions and Class Outlets sections.

However, these don't appear for me, just Class Identity and Interface Builder Identity... Where have they gone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interface Builder has gone through some changes recently.  Go to classes in the library panel, select the object from the top half you wish to inspect and the lower half of the screen has tabs for Lineage, Definitions, Outlets and Actions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure it makes much sense in that panel, since it seems like you have to create a subclass perfectly, and then there is no way to alter Actions and Outlets afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

In the library panel find the Segmented-Button, Click on classes. Find NSObject or any other class you would like to subclass.  Right click and "New subclass...", Name it something useful in the pop up like controller/AppController.  Find your newly named Class in the class list.  Now add all your actions/outlets in the Bottom of the library panel. 
Thanks to Convolution I would never have found this.  (Just thought I'd expand on the above tip).

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve my issue as the same as you. Before , I used a earlier version of IB, that's 3.1. And I can access "Class Actions and Class Outlets sections" on Tools-> Identity Inspector Panel. But after I choose another macbook (which IB is upgraded to version 3.2.1), I must access the corresponding section Library panel->Classes Tab->choose the specified object, then go to the panel's lower part(as illustrated by Convolution).